# Screen sharing between iPhone devices

Tags: ios5, screensharing

Can I share the screen of one iOS device with another iOS device from app ? 
Is it possible to implement above functionality using iOS SDK ? Does apple allow this type of app ? If anyone know about this , kindly let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple doesn't allow and also it is not possible in non-jailbroken devices.